# Does Spring Tool Suite run on Windows 10?

Tags: spring-tool-suite

Our agency requires that all Windows software be packaged by a central group. We've been using STS on Windows 7 for quite a while. I can't find any kind of official statement to indicate that it will run on Windows 10. Is STS working for folks running Windows 10 64 bit (HP hardware, if that makes a difference).

Several of us have tried finding information on the STS official site and I have submitted an issue to the STS issue tracker but it is unassigned. It would be helpful if we could point to some practical experience or success with this.

Thanks in advance,
Leila

Answer (score 0):

I received a very helpful comment from Martin Lippert on the STS issue tracker site. He said "The latest version of STS (3.8.3) as well as the upcoming version (3.8.4) are based on Eclipse Neon, which has Windows 10 as a supported target environment defined (https://www.eclipse.org/projects/project-plan.php?planurl=http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/development/plans/eclipse_project_plan_4_6.xml). Therefore you can run STS on Windows 10."

We also tested it on a test computer and it seems to be working fine.